# Input field that accept only positive numbers, two decimals and decimal comma, How?

Tags: angularjs

I have trying to do a directive which accepts only positive numbers, comma for decimals like European used to do and two decimals in that input field.

Not succeeded to do that.

I'm quite new with AngularJS and especially with directives like this.

Has anyone of you idea or sample how to implement this?

Input field with this directive should accept only positive numbers not any characters or other signs expect comma to indicate that two decimal numbers is needed.

Eg. 123.34 => 123,34 or 123.345 123,34 etc.

I have tried both in palce edit and formatting after losing focus from tht kind of field.

Any samples around?

Br Michael

Answer (score 3):

Its not exactly what you are looking for but this is direction:

Here we add commas and user can enter only integer.

[image]

```
fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = 123456879;
});

fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope'];


fessmodule.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber));
                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/704/)**</kbd>

Comment: Doesn't work for decimals, and will not work for every locale.

Comment: Thanks for this direction because in my case I can't use any 
kind of like <input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="foo"/> 
<output>{{ foo | number: 2 }}</output>. 

Localization in my case is not needed this time.

In place edit feature and blur.

This is quite difficult  task to implement.

Michael

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is non-trivial.

There are a LOT of localization considerations, and a lot of implications when parsing your number to return it to the model. While Angular has a formatter in the form of the `number` filter, it currently does not have a parser. So handling arbitrary entry from a text input will not be pleasant.

Prior to Angular, I spent time working on such a JavaScript implementation for a banking institution, and it was a lot more work than it appeared on the surface.

In truth, the *easy win* for something of this sort would be to leverage angular's number or currency filters to output a "preview" of sorts next to a standard number input:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="foo"/> 
<output>{{ foo | number: 2 }}</output>
```

or

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="foo"/> 
<output>{{ foo | currency }}</output>
```

The advantage here is Angular will handle the localization for you. You could even show/hide the output while the input is focused, I suppose.

Comment: Is step a built-in attribute or is it something you created? I'm not finding any documentation regarding this and I don't see how you implemented it if it is custom.

Comment: step is a built in attribute to HTML5 inputs that are type "number" or "range" for example. Check the `step` property under [MDN's documentation for HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)